# PopupControlExtender inside Gridview not closing

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, popupcontrolextender

A GridView will list rows which have to be approved/rejected. First column is named 'Action', which when clicked will display the ajax popupcontrolextender panel with two links (Approve/Reject). After the link is clicked, I need to update the status in the DB & refresh the GridView. ObjectDataSource is used to Bind the GridView. I have used the below code inside RowCommand event:

```
Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(index)

If e.CommandName = "Approve" Then
    BusinessLogicLayer.UpdateFileStatus(sID, Approve)
ElseIf e.CommandName = "Reject" Then
    BusinessLogicLayer.UpdateFileStatus(sID, Reject)
End If

GridView1.DataBind()
DirectCast(gvRow.FindControl("pceMenu"), AjaxControlToolkit.PopupControlExtender).Cancel()
```

HTML of  the TemplateField 'Action':

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" >
  <ItemTemplate>
    <ajax:PopupControlExtender ID="pceMenu" runat="server" TargetControlID="imgMenu" PopupControlID="pnlMenu" Position="Right" >  
    </ajax:PopupControlExtender> 
    <asp:Image ID="imgMenu" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/gear.png" CssClass="popupImage" /> 
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlMenu" runat="server" CssClass="popupControl" Width="85px" Height="50px" style="display:none;"> 
      <div class="menu-row" style="border-top: none;">
        <asp:Image ID="imgApprove" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/tick.png" style="float:left;"/>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkApprove" runat="server" Text="Approve" ToolTip="Approve" style="margin-left:10px;" CommandName="Approve" /> 
      </div> 
      <div class="menu-row">
        <asp:Image ID="imgReject" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/delete16.png" style="float:left;"/>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkReject" runat="server" Text="Reject" ToolTip="Reject" style="margin-left:10px;" CommandName="Reject" />
      </div> 
    </asp:Panel>
  </ItemTemplate> 
  <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="5%"/> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Tried the below methods, but no success:

- Suppress the panel's visibility using style="display:'';"
- Called the Cancel() method of the PopupControlExtender

**Note: The pop-up disappears if I don't bind the GridView inside the RowCommand event. But, I need to refresh the results displayed after Approve/Reject.**

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Nice first post!  But could you clarify your question in the body of your post to help others understand exactly what your asking? You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can hide [ajax control toolkit's](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.net) [modal popup extender](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.net/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) from code behind try this code:

```
IdOfYourModelPopup.Hide();
```